# MenuItem wont show up first on DropdownButton list?

Tags: reactjs

I am simply trying to have a "default" menuItem show first that says "Selected" before the dynamically created part of the dropdownButton MenuItem is made. However, the below will add it to the list, but will show an item from the list first instead of "Selected". How can "Selected" be listed first when the button is created?

```
    <div class="buttonContainer">
          <ButtonToolbar>
            <DropdownButton bsSize="large" title={key} id="dropdown-size-large" activeKey={key} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                <MenuItem eventKey="Select">Select</MenuItem>
              {list.map(item => (
                <MenuItem eventKey={list.item}>{list.item}</MenuItem>
              ))}
            </DropdownButton>
         </ButtonToolbar>
   <div>
```

Comment: What library are you using for ButtonToolbar, DropdownButton, and MenuItem? Also, can you elaborate a little on exactly what you're wanting here. From the looks of it, you'll get a list back starting with Select followed by your list items as the children of DropdownButton and your question seems to indicate that's what you want. I would suggest getting the React Developer Tools for Chrome, open the browser console, clicking on the react tab, locate your component, and see if what is rendered is what you desire.

Comment: OP probably wants to sort on "selected" first and then run Map on items

Comment: This is using bootstrap react.